# How to connect 5 kW electric heater to the weak wiring in house?

Tags: power, safety, load-regulation

The water heater has a 5kW heater and requires 20A.

Unfortunately, the wiring in our house is old and this allows us to get only 10A.

Is there an easy way to reduce energy/current consumption and connect such a powerful heater to the network with an energy consumption of about 2kW?

I found, that "Triac power regulation" can be used to reduce the power consumption:
[image]

I've tested schematic using LTspice and found, that peak current is the same (very big) - 20A:
[image]

In this case, power consumption is about 2.5kW, but I am worrying about weak house wiring because of peak current is 20A. I'm not sure if it is safe.

P.S. The voltage at the outlet is AC 220V (50Hz).

Comment: If you're wiring is causing you to lose half the supply voltage to your water heater then you need an electrician or a bunch of fire extinguishers.

Comment: @Andyaka no it's just a way to combine whole house heating with water heating, using the house wiring as the heating element

Comment: @BeB00 someone might take you seriously on this.

Comment: @Andyaka This is definitely not a voltage divider. TRIAC works in key mode (open-close). Important question here was: "Is it safe to use this scheme for the case described above?"

Comment: Your wiring isn't safe period.

Comment: I understand, but does the wire melt?

Comment: Even if the wire doesnt melt, it could still definitely cause a fire in your walls (not a great place to have a fire)

Comment: Got it. Neil_UK in his answer to this question also wrote that proposed idea is not safe. I'm seeking another solution, but I'm not sure if it will be as easy as I wish... Thank you both for your answers and comments!

Comment: Boarderline XY problem. Get yourself a different heater with lower power or call an electrician to up-rate your service.

Comment: @winny I agree. Funny thing is that 5kW heater was installed exactly by the electrician from our local service. :(

Comment: Take it up with him/her instead of trying to invent a way around the problem!

Comment: You should really just install a new wire. It's possible. It's not black magic. You might need to hire an electrician to do it. You will thank us for the lack of headaches later. It will Just Work.

Comment: @user253751 Unfortunately, this is not my house, and the owner has already made repairs in the rooms. Anyway, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Rental house with unsafe heaters is even worse; this is definitely the landlord's problem and you should insist they fix it.

Comment: Check your heater type - there MIGHT be lower power heating elements available for it. Elements fail so they are cheap and replaceable. Remove connections and simply unscrew. (Drain the water first!)

Comment: I don't get how you get 20A rating. Even if rated at 230 volts a 5kW heater would drain 21,74 amperes.

Comment: 5kW looks like a tankless heater. Suppose you make it work with much lower power consumption - then its heating ability will reduce too and the heater might get useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running double the current through your wiring causes 4 times the dissipation in it, and so more or less 4 times the temperature rise (assuming conduction and natural convection as the principal sources of cooling at these temperatures). It's the temperature rise that causes the damage, softening insulation, starting fires etc.

Using the triac circuit is supplying power for 50% of the time. Although that would cut your heater dissipation in half, it only cuts your '4 times too much' wiring dissipation in half as well, leaving the wiring temperature still double what it should be. Given that the existing '10 A' wiring is rated for a significant temperature rise, even twice the rise is still far too hot for safe operation of the plastic insulation.

Insulation relies on being solid. At double the rated temperature rise above ambient, it's likely to soften, and flow away from anywhere there's pressure on it. This could cause conductors to contact each other. In the best case, the short would open the circuit breaker. You'd then have a dead circuit that would have to be repaired/rewired by an electrician. In the worst case, an arc between the conductors could start a fire.

Your only two sensible options are to rewire, or to buy a much lower power heater. Or three options, stop using the heater. Or four options, continue using the heater, and have a good story ready for the fire investigators.

Or the fifth option, install a 2:1 step down transformer at the sending end of your 10 A feeder. This will run the wiring at 10 A, so the wiring will run at rated, but the heater will run at 1.25 kW. It might be that buying a suitably sized transformer is competitive with hiring an electrician to run a 20 A cable. It will also only work if this is an isolated feeder to only your heater, due to the non standard voltage.

What about the 6th option of using the triac to turn on for less than 1/2 a cycle? That's possible. If you turn the triac on for the last 1/3rd of the cycle, then you'll deliver about half the rms current. The heater and wiring will dissipate 25% of their 'full' power. You don't need to worry about the peak current, just the rms aka heating effect, at least for modest peaks like this.

Comment: I am not sure about "4 times temp rise". Temp is not directly related with the heat dissipation. I request you to reconsider this claim. :)

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Edited first paragraph. Happy?

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you for your answer! It sounds convincing. Anyway, I think that there is a chance to control power/current not causing a fire. And yes, I'm not talking about mentioned schematic (your words + my worrying make me careful). How about idea to control input voltage and open TRIAC only in moments of time, when input voltage is less than 100V? Peak current in this case will be 10A.

Comment: @neil_UK - very. Have a great day :)

Comment: @lollol So you are worried about the safety of wires, and yet, not even slightly worried about your circuit design, driving 5kW/20A load safely, without starting a fire if it malfunctions? Most likely you are not legally qualified to design and install electrical equipment, so guess what the fire investigators and insurance companies think about that, if the house burns down or someone dies from electric shock, etc?

Comment: @Justme I'm worrying about everything (safety is a priority number one). That is why I was asking a question at this place. Do not worry, I have the appropriate education.

Comment: @Neil_UK BTW, at least, it is possible to safely connect 5kW to 220V*10A wiring, for example, using powerful transformer (220V->110V). At least, in theory.

Comment: It's still no where near four times the temperature rise. Radiation alone is T^3. You'll end up witht a mixture of radiation and convection, so temperature will be slightly less then the third root of power dissipation.

Comment: @winny Stefans Law is T^4, not T^3. Conduction is basically T^1. Natural convection (ie laminar rather than turbulent flow) is roughly T^1. At the temperatures involved with moderately overheated conductors in a typical domestic cabling environment, I maintain that temperature linear terms significantly exceed the radiation terms. The temperature rise will therefore be roughly linear with power.

Comment: @Neil_UK "The temperature rise will therefore be roughly linear with power.". In this case it is ok to use Triac schematic, because the power dissipation on wires will be taken as an integral of squared current multiplied by resistance on time and it can be tuned to become less than 2kW.

Comment: @lollol No, heat in the wires goes as I^2, so 4x, before multiplying by duty cycle. I'll address the partial cycles in my answer.

Comment: @Neil_UK But current flows not full cycle (please, check the picture from the question).

Comment: @l Hmmm, an hour, and nobody has pulled me up about the mistake I *did* make, now fixed!

Comment: @Neil_UK Anyway, you've fixed your answer. Probably, I should accept it. BTW, it is possible to get 2kW if to use step-down transformer 220V->140V, but as you said: "... is competitive with hiring an electrician to run a 20 A cable.". Thanks!

Comment: @lollol I specified a 2:1 transformer, not a higher ratio like 220:140 stepdown. Consider the heater and the wiring are two resistors in series. Whatever the rms current, they will both reduce their dissipation in the same ratio. You have to get the rms current down to 10 A from 20 A to protect the wiring, which if done via a transformer requires a 2:1 stepdown. If done with a triac chopper, it requires the trailing 33% of each sinuousodal cycle.

Comment: @lollol - once you get the circuit and safety sorted, you will need a huge cooling system. Triacs get pretty hot at larger currents. Assume a volt drop across the triac and multiply with the current. That's the power dissipation happening in that small component. Need to put the component on a heat sink.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Thanks for noting that. I know about this. Power dissipation will be around 50 Wt and yes, in this case I do really need a radiator.

Answer (score 1):

Water heater elements are replaceable. They have to be because the elements die - often long before the heater tank does.
So the solution to your problem is easy - remove the 5kW element and replace it with a lower power one, somewhere in the 2kW - 2.5kW range.
Just remember that your water will take significantly longer to heat up.

Answer (score 0):

Peak current is not a problem. Average current is. As Neil_UK explained, the risk is from heating. That's why the circuit breaker must never exceed the capacity of the wire.
First see what wire it is. If it's 2.5mm you can safely use 20A. If it's 1.5mm, only 16A.

Anyway, I would NOT recommend a regulator circuit on a 1.5kW installation because the regulator itself will heat. If not the wires. Wiring correctly the circuit must also be done carefully. Components should be rated high. You can do mistakes etc.
You will also waste power. Maybe 10%.

The best is still taking a drill and buying a 4mm cable (or at least 2.5mm) and a dedicated 20A circuit breaker. You don't need an electrician to do this.

But you will need an engineer to design your triac circuit properly. ;)

•1,5 mm² → 10 A → 2 300 W

•2,5 mm² → 16 A → 3 680 W (also good for 20A - 4 400 W)

•4 mm² → 25 A → 5 750 W

•6 mm² → 32 A → 7 360 W

•10 mm² → 40 A → 9 200 W.

Comment: @Fredler Thanks for your advice! Do you really mean diameter of the wire, or did you mean "wire cross section"? Anyway, it also depends on the material of the wire, etc. I agree with you about additional losses in transformer.

Comment: @lollol Depending on your country wires sold in electric stores are measured either in square mm (Europe) or AWG gauge (US). I gave you indication for sqaure mm, that's cross section surface. See my edited reply